# Virtual box File access

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, android

I'm running Android on a VirtualBox on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine.
I want to know if there is a way to access system files and images stored within this virtual android machine from within my host ubuntu machine.
Is there something like a hidden file path I`m missing in nautilus or something)?

Comment: You can probably ssh into it.

Comment: You can install airdroid on your android vm and share through network with any browser.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not possible. virtual machines have special files that contains your second OS. Perhaps you can do it trough your VM software.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual Box "Shared Folder" access is unavailable to Android hosts. We can however share guest files through network access via [ADB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760490/android-x86-on-virtualbox-android-connected-but-not-online), SSH or Samba.

This may require the installation of an SSH or Samba server on the guest Android.